# my buttons and textview not display on screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiview, xcode6

i am creating three buttons and one uitextview dynamically but when i run the program its not display on my screen

this my code to create dynamic buttons and textview

```
   -(void)getSmsdisplay

 {
   self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] 
   applicationFrame]];
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   UITextView *textview=[[UITextView alloc]init];
   [button setTitle:@"Comment" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button1 setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button1 setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   //listen for clicks
   [button addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(btncomment:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(btnShare:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button2 addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(Like:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   smsdata *data=[[smsdata alloc]init];

   [textview setText:data.Data];
   [self.view addSubview:textview];



  //add the button to the view
  [self.view addSubview:button];
   [self.view addSubview:button1];
   [self.view addSubview:button2];

   }
```

Comment: You are reassigning self.view to another, which is not added as the subview of any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your coding is fine , but u r not added the frame for `UIButton` and `UItextview`

```
-(void)getSmsdisplay

{
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]
                                           applicationFrame]];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


UITextView *textview=[[UITextView alloc]init];

button.frame=CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 50);

  button1.frame=CGRectMake(20, 150, 200, 50);

  button2.frame=CGRectMake(20, 300, 200, 50);

button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
  button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
  button2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

[button setTitle:@"Comment" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//listen for clicks
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(btncomment:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 addTarget:self
            action:@selector(btnShare:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button2 addTarget:self
            action:@selector(Like:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



[textview setText:@"karthik"];
[self.view addSubview:textview];



//add the button to the view
[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];

}
```

the output is [image]

Comment: i want this button on bottom of my window like horizontally

Comment: just change the frame,

Comment: means i am not getting u

Comment: but i want to set auto layout when i rotating screen its not display

Comment: if u rotating the screen u need to change the all frame size or embed in scrollview and set the correct constraints brother

Comment: give me sample example

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning self.view to another UIView instance, which has not been added to the viewController. Note that self.view is already initialised in a viewController and it is dangerous to reassign the same.

Also, you have not set any frames for the Buttons and textview.

The following code should make it work.

```
-(void)getSmsdisplay

 {
   UIView *smsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] 
   applicationFrame]];
   [self.view addSubview: smsView]; //The new view needs to be added to something!

   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   UITextView *textview=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(20,20,100,50)];
   [button setTitle:@"Comment" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button1 setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button1 setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   //listen for clicks
   [button addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(btncomment:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(btnShare:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button2 addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(Like:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   smsdata *data=[[smsdata alloc]init];

   [textview setText:data.Data];
   [smsView addSubview:textview];

  button.frame=CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 50);
  button1.frame=CGRectMake(20, 150, 200, 50);
  button2.frame=CGRectMake(20, 300, 200, 50);

  //add the button to the view
  [smsView addSubview:button];
   [smsView addSubview:button1];
   [smsView addSubview:button2];

   }
```

Comment: tanx for support to the questioner,your answer also fine